# Perl autoboxing in conjunction with operator overloading doesn't seem to work?

Tags: perl, operator-overloading, autoboxing

I'm attempting to use both Perl's autoboxing functionality and operator overloading functionality, and they don't seem to be working in tandem.

Is it possible I am missing some nuance of how to use overload properly, or is this some sort of odd deviant behavior?

Sample Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package overload_me;
use overload('+' => "overloaded_add");
sub overloaded_add{
    my ($me, $him) = @_;
    $me+$him+1;
}

use autobox NUMBER => 'overload_me';
my $autoboxing_test = 4->overloaded_add(5);
my $overloading_test = 4 + 5;
print "Autoboxing test: 4+5=$autoboxing_test 
Overloading test: 4+5=$overloading_test\n";
```

Test output:

```
Autoboxing test: 4+5=10 Overloading test: 4+5=9
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autoboxing doesn't cause `4` to be an instance of `overload_me`. It causes *method calls* with `4` on their left hand side to call methods in `overload_me`. This is a subtle distinction but an important one, because it means that `overload` just doesn't apply at all. `4` isn't an object and doesn't belong to any class. It's still just `4` and when you calculate `4 + 5` it's still just `4 + 5`.

From [the autobox docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/autobox):

> The autoboxing is transparent: boxed values are not blessed into their (user-defined) implementation class (unless the method elects to bestow such a blessing) - they simply use its methods as though they are.

Comment: Curses! Thank you. Do you happen to know a way to achieve the functionality I was looking for in Perl, in an implicit manner?

Comment: use `overload::constant` (part of overload.pm) to get `integer` and `float` really blessed into your number class. But just be advised that this is likely to make lots and lots of code unhappy at you :)

Comment: @Clocky should have pinged you on the previous comment, so you get this one instead.

Comment: => do you have any particular examples of code that will break with overloaded numbers?